# Is there any way to make an API within the same URL of React.js application just like Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

In Next.js, I can access my application on `localhost:3000`, and access to my API from `localhost:3000/api/hello` .

Is there any way to do this by using React.js and some other framework like Express.js?

What is the solution if I don't want to use Next.js?

Both on development and production.

***EDIT:***

**In production:**

I just deployed my express.js app to my shared hosting
using `app.listen()` and it works fine because in production we don't or we shouldn't specify the port as I know.

So there's no need to worry about ports being different just because they are in development.

**In develoment:**

I haven't tried anything yet but as jcubic mentioned maybe we need a proxy.

Comment: You mean access the api and the dev server that runs React on the same port?

Comment: @CStudent yes, because I want to prevent browser to send preflight requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can because ReactJS doesn't run on a port it runs in the browser you only get the files from the server.

This is usually how applications are created. when you run your app locally you have a dev server to simplify development (e.g. by adding live or hot reloader) but for production, you don't need a dedicated server for your React app, since React app are static files.

So in order to have API and React on the same port you need to write Express.js app where you write an API and serve static files (for instance in your public directory) as root path `'/'`.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

// your react app accessed with /
app.use(express.static('public'));

// your api
app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

And for development, you usually create a Proxy to run the backend on the same port as the app that runs on dev server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but I did the trick by just deploying the express.js using app.listen() with no arguments and in production  we don't or we shouldn't specify the port so now I have them both. '/' for my  react app and '/api/' for my express.js server

Comment: @AliBot this is just an example from Express.js documentation, port is optional and default to 80 http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.listen_path_callback